# How to resolve the error 'EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)' in Ionic 4 to IOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, ionic4

I have an app made in Ionic 4 that uses Firebase as backend. It works flawlessly on my real iPhone 7 device with iOS 12.2 and all simulators running on MacOS. But when I launch to test in TestFlight it gives the EXC_CRASH (SIGILL) error that I can not track and troubleshoot.
I already researched all the similar issues here and in other forums and found little and the ones I found did not solve my problem.
How do I solve this: make my app work locally and in production in TestFlight?

```
<platform name="ios">
        <config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>You can take photos</string>
        </config-file>
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativestorage" spec="2.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="2.6.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="3.0.0">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepath" spec="1.5.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="6.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="4.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" spec="2.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder" spec="3.1.3">
        <variable name="LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION" value="Use geocoder service" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="5.4.4">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="24.1.1+" />
    </plugin>
    <feature name="SocialSharing">
        <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.SocialSharing" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SocialSharing">
        <param name="ios-package" value="SocialSharing" />
    </feature>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player" spec="2.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="4.2.1">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="384988252281761" />
        <variable name="APP_NAME" value="“br.com.easychurchmobile”" />
        <variable name="FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS" value="false" />
        <variable name="FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION" value="4.40.0" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="7.0.1">
        <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="MY_REVERS" />
        <variable name="WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID" value="MY_WEB_APP" />
        <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="11.8.0" />
    </plugin>
    <engine name="android" spec="7.1.4" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="4.5.5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. I refitted the build with

```
ionic cordova ios --release
```

Before I was doing with

```
ionic cordova ios --prod
```

Incredibly, it solved the issue.